# Different Results Of Report Generation In IReport preview And Using Jasperreports API

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, java

I want my report pages to have A4 format. to do this i used 'report->Page Format...' in iReport. In PDF preview everything seems to be ok. But when i use the .jasper file to generate report from my application it has only one long page instead of a couple of standart pages. What is wrong with it? how can i tell jasper to generate multi-page report?
iReport version is 3.7.1
Both generated report and iReport preview i'm viewing with adobe reader.
Thanks for your replies

Comment: Did you check the report's `isIgnorePagination` property?

Comment: I found the solution. It appears that you should explicitly set IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION parameter to false in pdf exporter. Unckecking it in iReport doesn't work.

params.put("IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION", false); I cannot post an answer right away because of my reputation level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It appears that you should explicitly set IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION parameter to false in pdf exporter. Unckecking it in iReport doesn't work.

```
params.put("IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION", false);
JasperPrint reportOut = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, params, dataset);
```

I hope it will help somebody